# Angular parsing reference of second component to the first one

Tags: angular

I have this question :

**component1**

```html
<component1 [Component2Reference]="nameOfSecondComponent"></component1>
```

```js
    class Component1 {
       @Input() Component2Reference: any;
    }
```

**component2**

```html
    <component2 #nameOfSecondComponent></component2>
```

```js
    class MainClass {
       @ViewChild() nameOfSecondComponent: any;
    }
```

The two components belong to the MainClass view and I'd like to parse a reference of the second component to the first one so that i can control its behaviour. But this doesn't work for me.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: i'd consider using `Output` events instead of what you're doing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass id of the reference into `ViewChild`.

```js
class MainClass {
  @ViewChild('nameOfSecondComponent') nameOfSecondComponent: any;
}
```

Comment: oh i had this before @ViewChild('name1') name2: any; and i was parsing the name1 instead of name2 silly me :) but thanks a lot...

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. :( :)

Comment: There’s an icon below to mark it as an answer. Below the vote icons.